# Xcode suddenly stuck in pull source control

Tags: xcode, git, source-control-explorer

all the time source control working well but suddenly it take endless time to loading remotes "pull" stuck there as image

[image]

I did more than 7 committees and i can't get any thing from repository

i don't now why suddenly happen that

any suggestion to how solve this issue

Comment: See the Cancel button? Click it.

Comment: @matt. We are discussing here for a solution. Not just skip the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a networking issue. Kill Xcode and try again. You could also try pulling form the command line or some other client such as SourceTree or Tower.